# Redux state is not being passed to nested router component despite fetching the state directly in that component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have a react-redux state that is a fetched array of 'products' objects from a backend database. I have a 'ProductList' component that receives the fetched objects and creates a list of products. I am directly calling my 'fetchProducts()' method within this 'ProductList' component. This 'ProductList' component is able to be refreshed and the fetched products will persist and reappear after each refresh.

However, I have another 'ViewProduct' component that is in a nested Router route in which I am also fetching the same 'products' array. The problem is in this component, on refresh, the 'products' state does not persist and returns undefined despite the fact that I am also directly calling 'fetchProducts()' inside the component.

I am passing the products array directly into the 'ProductView' component yet it does not persist on refresh the same way my 'ProductsList' component does.

Here is my 'AllProductsList' component that SUCCESSFULLY persists the products data on refresh. It is located in a route '/products/all':

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { fetchProducts } from '../actions/productAction.js';
import ProductCard from '../components/ProductCard.js';

class AllProductsList extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProducts()
  }

  renderDiv = () => {
    return this.props.products.map((product) =>
      <ProductCard key={product.id} product={product} />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderDiv()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

AllProductsList.propTypes = {
  fetchProducts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  products: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  products: state.products.items,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchProducts })(AllProductsList)
```

And here is the problem 'ProductView' component that does NOT persist the product data after refresh. This component is located on route /product/:id :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { fetchProducts } from '../actions/productAction.js';

class ProductView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      buttonMessage: 'Add to cart',
      quantity: 0,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProducts()
  }

  quantityChangeReader = (e) => {
    this.setState({ quantity: e.target.value })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>   
<li>this.props.products[this.props.match.params.productId].name</li>
<li>this.props.products[this.props.match.params.productId].comments</li>
<li>this.props.products[this.props.match.params.productId].photos[1].url</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ProductView.propTypes = {
  fetchProducts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  products: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  products: state.products.items,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchProducts })(ProductView)
```

Parent component of 'ProductView', which is routed to in the App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ProductView from '../components/ProductView.js';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductViewContainer = ({ match, products }) => (

      <div>
        <Route path={`${match.url}/:productId`} render={routerProps => <ProductView {...routerProps} /> }/>
      </div>
)

export default ProductViewContainer
```

In this second scenario, for component ProductView, on refresh, it will return the error message, 'Cannot read .name of undefined.' Yet in the first component ('AllProductsList') refreshing will successfully return the array again.

As requested, here is the router:

```
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <NavBar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Carousel} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={OurStory} />
          <Route exact path="/products/necklaces" component={NecklacesList} />
          <Route exact path="/products/bracelets" component={BraceletsList} />
          <Route exact path="/products/earrings" component={EarringsList} />
          <Route exact path="/products/all" component={AllProductsList} />
          <Route exact path="/events" component={Events} />
          <Route exact path="/cart" component={Cart} />
          <Route path='/product' render={routerProps => <ProductViewContainer {...routerProps} />} />
          <Credits />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
```

Comment: Can you show the router?

Comment: @GaëlS, yes I've just edited my post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ProductView` component, `this.props.products` will be `undefined` when the component renders for the first time. This will happen on page refresh or when you hit the product id route directly in the browser, either of which will reset your redux state.

To curb this, you'll need to add a check in your component to confirm if the `products` prop has been populated.

Like this...

```
render() {
  const { products } = this.props;
  if (products.length) {
    // render the rest of your view
  } else {
    // products is still fetching...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ladi. Would I put the check in the actual ProductView component or the parent component?

Comment: inside the ProductView component

Answer (score 0):

React-redux does not persist data when you refresh page. If you want to persist data, store in localstorage. 
When you refresh page, initially `this.props.products` will be null. Once data get fetch, this.props.products will have remote data, and component will get re-render. You can put if condition in ProductView component